# how to create an array of Bitset in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, bit-manipulation, bitset

I want to create an array of Bitset .Binary Bitset(example "100","1010",etc)
After that I want to input from user and store in the the Bitset .
I have tried the following line but it says error.

```
#include<bits/stdc++> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
  int n,i;
  string bit_string; 
  cin>>n  // size of Bitset array.
  bitset<8> brr[n];//  
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    cin>>bit_string;
    brr[i](bit_string);
  }



  return 0; 
}
```

I want to create n Bitset each of size 8 bits.Where n is given by user.
my input is binary string like.
"110010","001110"
please help

Comment: Not directly related to your question but worth reading anyway: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: `cin>>n; bitset<8> brr[n];` is a variable-length array and not supported by C++. Use a std::vector

Comment: What is the error it says?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic count of the objects , Please try vector<> instead of array[]

```
#include<bits/stdc++> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    string bit_string;
    cin >> n;  // size of Bitset array.

    vector<bitset<8>> arr;      //size()=>0
    arr.resize(n);      //size()=>n

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> bit_string;
        bitset<8>& br = arr[i]; //get the i of n

        int maxlen = 8;
        if (bit_string.size() <= 8)
            maxlen = bit_string.size();
        else
            cout << "warning invalid len " << bit_string.size() << " of " << bit_string << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < maxlen; j++)
        {
            if (bit_string[j] == '1')
                br.set(j, true);
        }

        //cout << endl << br << endl;   //output test
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you still want to use array ,  please try this way

```
#include<bits/stdc++> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, i;
    string bit_string;
    cin >> n;  // size of Bitset array.

    bitset<8>* arr = new bitset<8>[n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> bit_string;
        bitset<8>& br = arr[i]; //get the i of n

        int maxlen = 8;
        if (bit_string.size() <= 8)
            maxlen = bit_string.size();
        else
            cout << "warning invalid len " << bit_string.size() << " of " << bit_string << endl;

        for (int j = 0; j < maxlen; j++)
        {
            if (bit_string[j] == '1')
                br.set(j, true);
        }

        //cout << endl << br << endl;   //output test
    }

    delete[] arr;   //IMPROTAND , delete the array and free memory

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I posted another solution for you . use  bitset<8>* arr = new bitset<8>[n];

Answer (score 3):

The error ocurrs because you are trying to creat a C-style array using `n` which is not compile-time constant. It's not possible to creat a C-style array without being `n` known at compile time.

The following is a good way to do what you want

Creat a `std::vector<std::bitset<8>>` to hold your `bitset<8>`s, as follows.

Note that the code ignores the excess of characters in strings iput like `"111111110"` (makes it `"11111111"`) and treats any character except `'1'` as if it were `'0'` and if the input string is less than 8 characters, the code adds zeros by the default of the `bitset`s

```
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n, i;
    std::string bit_string;
    std::cout << "Enter the size";
    std::cin >> n; // size of Bitset array.
    std::vector<std::bitset<8>> brr(n);//
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> bit_string;
        for (int j{}; j < bit_string.size() && j < 8; ++j) {
            brr[i][j] = (bit_string[j] == '1') ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
    //To test

    for(auto const& el :brr)
    {
        for(int i{}; i < 8;)
            std::cout << el[i++];
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

See [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) 
and
[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)